# Log in to AWS using Access Key ID and Secret Access Key ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-iam

In AWS, how do I use my Access Key ID and Secret Access Key?

I can't use them in IAM users sign-in link.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Access Key ID and Secret Access Key are for API/CLI/SDK access. For IAM sign-in (dashboard) you need the username and password. When a new IAM user is added, the user gets username, password, access key and secret key, and the IAM URL from the IAM admin.

Comment: I'm follwing : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/s3transferutility.html  ....... where in the android call do you specify the Access Key ID and Secret Access Key??

Comment: @Mike6679 if you use the IAM roles as described under `Grant Access to Your S3 Resources` in that link, you do not need to specify the access key and the secret key.

Comment: but where would the Access Key ID and Secret Access Key be specified if you had to ?

Answer (score 21):

To complement helloV's answer : you can also use the access key and secret key to generate a signed URL to the console.  This signed URL will allow to access the console, without being prompted for username and password.

Many AWS customers are using this technique to provide single-sign on for Federated users.

More details are available at : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/UsingSTS/STSMgmtConsole-manualURL.html

Comment: Note for others: I try the ruby code but it is outdate. It is better to use python code.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add, for anyone who might need it, if your intent is to use the AWS CLI, running `aws configure` will prompt you for both.